# Cognito listUsers with aws-sdk is very slow

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I'm creating one api with express-js and Cognito for users management, but every query in cognito takes at least 700ms to return the data... this is very slow!!
How can i speed this up?

Have configs in AWS to reduce network delay?

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const Cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  region: '...',
  accessKeyId: '...',
  secretAccessKey: '...',
});

const data = await Cognito.getUser({
  AccessToken
}).promise();

return {
  ...data,
  userName: data.Username,
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm dealing with the same issues trying to remove the aws SDK from my front end to reduce the bundle size.

Comment: Hit the same issue, it takes 30+ seconds to list 10000 or so users.